# In Angular project reference to php script give 404 (Not Found) locally, but works on live site

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, http-status-code-404, yeoman, filepath

I'm new to Angular and I'm using Yeoman for scaffolding and Grunt for builds. I'm attempting a post to a php script with the following code:

```
 $http({
  method  : 'POST',
  url     : '/components/contact/test.php',
  data    : $.param($scope.user),  // pass in data as strings
  headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }  // set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
 });
```

When I run this on my local server I get the following error

```
POST http://localhost:9000/components/contact/test.php 404 (Not Found)
```

How ever when I do a build and push to my web site it does find the php script (I have checked and it is there locally). I tried a number of different variations on the file path and none seem to work. Can anyone explain what's going on here?

Comment: it seems more an error on your php server configuration than about angular. What did you do to debug you php script in localhost? can you make a screenshot of your network in firebug? if you try to access that address in the browser what' happening?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, I cannot seem to find a fix for it at the moment. Whats happening when I got to that URL in the browser is it actually downloads the script.

Comment: @borracciaBlu it seem that when I try to access any files in my main "app/" directory I get a 403 Forbidden.

Comment: @MikeHuebner if the file you are trying to access is in php it's because you have a bad server setup. are you using a lamp|wamp|mamp?

Comment: @MikeHuebner, I'm using MAMP

Comment: @BenPearce the 403 Forbidden it's because the permissions of the files, it means you can not read the files. Again your problem seems to be php not angular. Which OS are you running? Which web server are you using in local ? apache nginx?

Comment: @BenPearce mamp is using the port 8080 not the 9000 try to replace it http://localhost:9000 to http://localhost:8080

Comment: @borracciaBlu my MAMP comes through on port 8888. I get the same if I try to access it there. I should add that if I try to enter the URL for the script (or any other script in my '/app' directory) I get 403 Forbidden.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80350/discussion-between-borracciablu-and-ben-pearce).